# How to pass Model Inside Another Model in Razor View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code for razor view.
here id is an integer but FulfillForm in another view model. While passing it in a controller the view model is null. I cannot pass value in the view Model. How can I solve this??

```
<div id="editWorkPerformed">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateWorkPerformedOrderToFulfill", "contracts", new { id = Model.Id, FulfillForm = Model.FulfillForm }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
    {
        <div class="mb15">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FulfillForm.WorkPerformed, new { @class = "ckeditor" })
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" value="Save Changes" />
    }
</div>
```

The View Model for the razor page is

```
public class ContractViewModel
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public FullFillOrderViewModel FulFillForm {get; set;}
}

public class FulFillForm 
{
  public string WorkPerformed {get; seet;}
}
```

and contract controller accepts parameter as `ContractViewModel`

Comment: Post your UpdateWorkPerformedOrderToFulfill method.

Comment: your controller action method looks like this `Public ActionResult UpdateWorkPerformedOrderToFulfill(int id,FulFillForm FulfillForm)`